# doing optimizations in matlab: figuring out constraint equation

Tags: matlab, optimization, constraints

I have N lines that are defined by a y-intercept and an angle, q.  The constraint is that all N lines must intersect at one point.  The equations I can come up with to eventually get the constraint are these:

```
Y = tan(q(1))X + y(1)
Y = tan(q(2))X + y(2)
...
```

I can, by hand, get the constraint if N = 3 or 4 but I am having trouble just getting one constraint if N is greater than 4.  If N = 3 or 4, then when I solve the equations above for X, I get 2 equations and then can just set them equal to each other.  If N > 4, I get more than 2 equations that equal X and I dont know how to condense them down into one constraint.  If I cannot condense them down into one constraint and am able to solve the optimization problem with multiple constraints that are created dynamically (depending on the N that is passed in) that would be fine also.

To better understand what I am doing I will show how I get the constraints for N = 3.  I start off with these three equations:

```
Y = tan(q(1))X + y(1)
Y = tan(q(2))X + y(2)
Y = tan(q(3))X + y(3)
```

I then set them equal to each other and get these equations:

```
tan(q(1))X + y(1) = tan(q(2))X + y(2)
tan(q(2))X + y(2) = tan(q(3))X + y(3)
```

I then solve for X and get this constraint:

```
(y(2) - y(1)) / (tan(q(1)) - tan(q(2))) = (y(3) - y(2)) / (tan(q(2)) - tan(q(3)))
```

Notice how I have 2 equations to solve for X.  When N > 4 I end up with more than 2.  This is OK if I am able to dynamically create the constraints and then call an optimization function in MATLAB that will handle multiple constraints but so far have not found one.

Comment: What's your end-goal? Do you just want to find the lines, or do the lines represent something else in a problem that needs optimization?

Comment: the lines represent something else.  The big picture is I know an angle that is an estimate of q.  since it is an estimate, none of the lines intersect.  I need to find the angle, q, so that all the lines then intersect while minimizing the distance between the estimated angle and the optimized angle.

Comment: but you are free to alter the `y`-intercepts?

Comment: I know the y-intercepts.  They will be given.  My algorithm should work for any y-intercepts that are defined though.  As in the user will input them into the function and the function will return the optimized angles based on the y-intercepts and the estimated angles

Comment: Are X and Y a number, a vector or a matrix?

Comment: X and Y are fixed values.  They represent the point (X,Y) where all of the lines intersect.  The value of X and Y are not known so should not show up in the constraint equation.

Comment: So you are looking for values of X,Y and q that will satisfy all the equations?

Comment: What I am given is a y-intercept and an angle, lets call it r, that defines a line.  I am given a bunch of these lines but they all do not intersect at one point.  I need to find revised angles, q, for each line so that all the lines intersect at one point (X,Y).  I am not trying to figure out X and Y, just q.

Comment: What I am trying to do is similar to the Lagrangian multiplier theory where you are given a function and some constraints and you have to maximize or minimize the function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You say the optimization algorithm needs to adjust `q` such that the "real" problem is minimized while the above equations also hold.

Note that the [fifth Euclid axoim](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallel_postulate) ensures that all lines will always intersect with all other lines, unless two `q`s are equal but the corresponding `y0`s are not. This last case is so rare (in a floating point context) that I'm going to skip it here, but for added robustness, you should eventually include it.

Now, first, think in terms of matrices. Your constraints can be formulated by the matrix equation:

```
y = tan(q)*x + y0
```

where `q`, `y` and `y0` are `[Nx1]` matrices, `x` an unknown scalar. Note that `y = c*ones(N,1)`, e.g., a matrix containing only the same constant. This is actually a non-linear constraint -- that is, it cannot be expressed as

```
A*q <= b   or   A*q == b
```

with `A` some design matrix and `b` some solution vector. So, you'll have to write a function defining this non-linear constraint, which you can pass on to an optimizer like `fmincon`. From [the documentation](http://www.mathworks.nl/help/optim/ug/fmincon.html):

> x = fmincon(fun,x0,A,b,Aeq,beq,lb,ub,nonlcon) subjects the
>   minimization to the nonlinear inequalities c(x) or equalities ceq(x)
>   defined in nonlcon. fmincon optimizes such that c(x) ≤ 0 and ceq(x) =
>   0. If no bounds exist, set lb = [] and/or ub = [].

Note that you were actually going in the right direction. You can solve for the `x`-location of the intersection for any pair of lines `q(n),y0(n)` and `q(m),y0(m)` with the equation:

```
x(n,m) = (y0(n)-y0(m)) / (q(m)-q(n))
```

Your `nonlcon` function should find `x` for *all* possible pairs `n,m`, and check if they are *all* equal. You can do this conveniently something like so:

```
function [c, ceq] = nonlcon(q, y0)
    % not using inequalities
    c = -1; % NOTE: setting it like this will always satisfy this constraint

    % compute tangents 
    tanq = tan(q);

    % compute solutions to x for all pairs 
    x = bsxfun(@minus, y0, y0.') ./ -bsxfun(@minus, tanq, tanq.');

    % equality contraints: they all need to be equal 
    ceq = diff(x(~isnan(x))); % NOTE: if all(ceq==0), converged.

end
```

Note that you're not actually solving for `q` explicitly (or need the y-coordinate of the intersection at all) -- that is all `fmincon`'s job.

You will need to do some experimenting, because sometimes it is sufficient to define

```
x = x(~isnan(x));
ceq = norm(x-x(1)); % e.g., only 1 equality constraint
```

which will be faster (less derivatives to compute), but other problems really need

```
x = x(~isnan(x));
ceq = x-x(1); % e.g., N constraints
```

or similar tricks. It really depends on the rest of the problem how difficult the optimizer will find each case.

Comment: Thanks!  I am still a little unsure on the y0 part.  y0 is going to be an Nx1 matrix but how do I pass it into fmincon's function?  The user is going to pass in y0 and the estimated angle associated with it.  I thought with fmincon, you would just pass in the handle to the nonlcon function so I am confused in how the function would know what my y0's are.

Comment: or I guess nonlcon could just be an inner function and then I would not need to have y0 be a parameter to it?

Comment: @user972276: You pass extra parameters like so: `fmincon(...., @(q)nonlcon(q, y0));`. Your `y0`s need to be known outside your objective function of course, otherwise, you'll have to do some other tricks to get it in.

Comment: @user972276: Or yes, you could make `nonlcon` a nested function, that too solves the problem.

Comment: oh ok.  That makes a lot of sense.  Thanks for your help!

Comment: Why should `y = c * ones(N,1)` be a non-linear constraint? Since `y` is given, you can directly write it as `ones(N,1) * c == y`, which is of the form `A * q == b`.

Comment: @silvado: the optimization variable is `q`, not `y`. It's then nonlinear because of the `tan()`.

Comment: @RodyOldenhuis: I'm referring to the third paragraph of your answer.

Comment: @silvado: I was writing an equation there, it's not a Matlab statement...Darn SO for not having MathML!

Comment: Ok, sorry, the "This" refers to the block constraint, not the constraint `y = c * ones(N,1)`. Need to look a little bit more back in the text...

Comment: @RodyOldenhuis: I seem to be getting an error when I try and implement it. It tells me fmincon only accepts inputs of type double. This is how I am calling it: p = fmincon(@(q)objFncn(q),[],[],[],[],[],[],@(q) nonlcon(q));. I just made nonlcon an inner function and copied and pasted it into my code.

Comment: @RodyOldenhuis: Turns out I missed an argument.  But now it is giving me an error in my objective function.  I imputed the parameters for if N = 3 but I get an error when it tries to access eta(3) (OutOfBounds) on the line:   y = y + theta(i) - eta(i).  I just have that statement in a for loop going from 1 to N.

Comment: @user972276: And what's `y`, `theta` and `eta` there?

Comment: ok sorry, I figured out I was hardcoding in the starting point to [0,0].  I fixed that to being zeros(1,N) and now get an error saying index exceeds matrix dimensions inside function nlconst (line 757).

Comment: y is just a summation of the total difference.  I am sure I could just do sum(theta(:) - eta(:)) or something but I was being on the safe side and just doing it that way.  theta is the estimated angle I know and eta is the angle I am trying to optimize

Comment: @RodyOldenhuis: it should actually be:  y = y + (theta(i) - eta(i))^2, I just typed it wrong.